# Is Apple Pay a required integration with new iOS apps?

Tags: ios, libgdx, in-app-purchase, robovm

I was planning on releasing my iOS app which I developed using libGDX/RoboVM but I can't make any test transactions anymore. I integrated the in-app-purchase SDK bindings and I was able to pull up my in-app-purchase items but can't anymore.

I'm not receiving any errors or messages. Just the "Buy Item" no longer shows up when I select something to purchase. Anyone know anything about this? Do I need to sign up for a Merchant ID now in the Apple Developer Console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IAP and Apple Pay are separate services for separate purposes.

Use In-App Purchase to sell software and services that pertain to things *in your app*: e.g. to unlock features, to subscribe to content updates, or to let a player gain in-game currency.

Use Apple Pay to sell things that the IAP agreement says you can't sell with IAP: real-world goods and services like shoes, meals, and taxi rides.

Not sure why IAP is giving you trouble, but it's definitely not something to do with Apple Pay.

Comment: Thanks... didn't understand much about Apple Pay. Now I guess I need to fix my in-app purchase issue.